# CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and CMAKE_MODULE_PATH are both empty,find_package still works

Tags: cmake

I am new to cmake and currently studying `find_package()`

from [doc : find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure)

> In Module mode, CMake searches for a file called Find.cmake. The file is first searched in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, then among the Find Modules provided by the CMake installation. If the file is found, it is read and processed by CMake. It is responsible for finding the package, checking the version, and producing any needed messages. Some find-modules provide limited or no support for versioning; check the module documentation.

for example,if I type `find_package(OpenCV)` and trun the cmake_find_debug_mode on by using :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON .
```

And, indeed the information print on the screen shows that it first try to search `{Path where I install cmake}/Modules/FindOpenCV.cmake` which i think but not truly sure is `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`,but not found, and it keep searching and finally found `OpenCVConfig.cmake` from the environment variable `OpenCV_DIR` that I define in one script.

Everything would I expect until I print out the message

```
message(STATUS "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH : ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH : ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
```

where the first one from [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) is defined as "Path used for searching by FIND_XXX(), with appropriate suffixes added".

And both of them return nothing...

I have two questions :

(1) why is `find_package` even `${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}` is empty?
(2) How to see all these environment variables define by cmake, e.g., CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ?

THANKS!!

Comment: thumbs up just for mentioning the gem `-DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON`.  That is pure gold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll be brief.

One important thing you should realize, is that, unlike GNU Makefile, CMake variables and environment variables are different. You seem to be mixing these terms in your question.

The `find_package` doc is very precise about its search procedure. I believe if you read the entire thing, you can answer this question yourself.

It's not that I don't want to answer in detail. It's just that I can't explain more clearly than the doc itself.

Instead I'll just make some key points:

- `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is where CMake searches "Find Modules", that is, `FindOpenCV.cmake`, if it exists, which does not in this world we live in, because of the next point.
- Because the authors of OpenCV provide a "Config" file, there is no need for anyone to write a "Find Module". `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is where CMake searches in lots of `find_xxx` APIs, including `find_package`, as it will be able to find `OpenCVConfig.cmake`, if you set the path correctly. But in your case, it's empty.
- You've set the env var `OpenCV_DIR`, which is precisely why everything works. According to the doc, this var helps find the package:

> Config mode search attempts to locate a configuration file provided by
> the package to be found. A cache entry called PackageName_DIR is
> created to hold the directory containing the file. By default the
> command searches for a package with the name PackageName. If the
> NAMES option is given the names following it are used instead of
> PackageName. The command searches for a file called
> PackageNameConfig.cmake or lower-case-package-name-config.cmake
> for each name specified. A replacement set of possible configuration
> file names may be given using the CONFIGS option. The search procedure
> is specified below. Once found, the configuration file is read and
> processed by CMake. Since the file is provided by the package it
> already knows the location of package contents. The full path to the
> configuration file is stored in the cmake variable
> _CONFIG.

> Search paths specified in cmake-specific environment variables. These
> are intended to be set in the user’s shell configuration, and
> therefore use the host’s native path separator (; on Windows and : on
> UNIX). This can be skipped if NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH is passed or
> by setting the CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH to FALSE:
>
> PackageName_DIR
>
> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
>
> CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH
>
> CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH

---

Edit:

Q: Why can CMake find OpenCV?

A: When `find_package(OpenCV)` is invoked, cmake will try to find `OpenCVConfig.cmake` from several locations. I've never bothered to remember the order of the locations (since I never have to).

It will look for:

1. CMake variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
2. Environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
3. CMake variable `OpenCV_DIR`
4. Environment variable `OpenCV_DIR`
5. And a lot more...

Note: CMake variable is a **semi-colon** separated string, while environment variable on Unix systems is **colon** separated string.

From your description, it seems CMake finds OpenCV through option #4.

Note: Refer to the doc for more details since:

- There are a lot more locations cmake will try looking up
- There are small difference in these variables. (For instance they are controlled on/off by different `find_package` parameters, etc.)

Normally, one does not specify paths to find on a per-package basis. This is why `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` (Option #1) is more often used. (If not set, it's empty by default)

Usually, it is set on the command line, like this:

```sh
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/install/path0;/install/path1/;...;/install/pathn/" .....
```

Then cmake will iterate each path separated by `;`.

However of course, per-package basis has its own value: to prevent using the wrong version if multiple versions are installed on your pc (I've seen too many issues with `/usr` vs `/usr/local/`), like this:

```sh
cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/path/to/the/version/I/meant/to/use .....
```

Comment: "But in your case, it's empty. (Because there exists a "Config" file, there is no need for anyone to write a "Find Module")" ,I don't quite understand this sentence,especially "there exists a "Config" file",what does this mean? And from this https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html , CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH seems mean to be empty by default .

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer Sorry, bad wording. I was meant to explain why there is no "FindOpenCV.cmake" in this world, not related at all to why CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is empty. I'll edit in a minute.

Comment: OK,One more question, from this link : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html it says by default  CMAKE_MODULE_PATH is empty,this actually confuses me ,it's set to be empty, however,when I run cmake and turn on the debug mode , cmake actually looks for package by finding something in {Path where I install cmake}/Modules/FindOpenCV.cmake.

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer Edited some more on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer, I think right now I know what's going on behind the scene, I would go through whole process briefly,please correct me if I am wrong : 
From doc it says : The file is first searched in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, then among the "Find Modules" provided by the CMake installation.
So in my case :  the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH is empty then cmake searchs in Find Modules , but still not able to find , and it change to  config mode and finally find one in "OpenCV_DIR" and find OpenCVConfig.cmake.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer That's pretty much it for your case. Just to be clear, `MODULE` mode looks for `FindOpenCV.cmake`; `Config` mode looks for `OpenCVConfig.cmake`. When the library **authors** provide a config file, there is no need for library **users** to write a `FindOpenCV.cmake`.